How do I turn on and test Granular Consent for mobile apps?
I got the following in an email from Google:
"Starting June 17, 2024, Google users will get more granular controls for sharing their Google account data with third-party apps. Test your app and make any necessary updates for the best user experience."
How do I turn on and test Granular Controls?
This is for Unity mobile games using Google Sign In.
Thanks
No info was provided or linked in the email.

You can refer to Test your updated application on handling granular permissions section to turn on granular permissions for testing.
Thanks
